# Parse child nodes in JSON with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

let's say that my controller produce such json:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$values": [{
        "$id": "2",
        "kodg": -1643387437,
        "name": null,
        "data": "2014-02-07T00:00:00",
        "pax": 2,
        "ch": 0
    }, {...}]
}
```

I need to reach somehow values in child nodes (starting from $id: 2) to be able to bind its to UI, but I do not have any idea how to do it. Please advise.

P.S. foreach is not working here:

```
<script>
        function BookViewModel() {
            var baseUri = '/api/grafik/205693'
            var self = this;
            self.kodg = ko.observable("");
            self.name = ko.observable("");
            self.data = ko.observable("");
            self.pax = ko.observable("");
            self.child = ko.observable("");
            var book = {
                kodg: self.kodg,
                name: self.name,
                data: self.data,
                pax: self.pax,
                child: self.child
            };
            self.book = ko.observable();
            self.books = ko.observableArray();
            $.getJSON(baseUri, self.books);
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new BookViewModel());
        });
    </script>
```

And this how I'm binding.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>kodg</td>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>pax</td>
                <td>child</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: books">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.kodg" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.name" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.data" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.pax" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.child" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Knockout documentation on `foreach` should do you good.

Comment: Wouldn't the $.getJSON(baseUri, self.books) mess up the self.books observableArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things.

Your usage of `self` is redundant. `self` is used to create a closure over the supposed context in a function that is passed, at a later time, as a callback of sorts - to preserve that context:

```
var self = this;
$('#target').on('click', function() {
   self.someMethodOfTheAboveThis(); 
});
```

Additionally, `getJSON` is asynchronous method and it doesn't do what, it seems, you think it does.

Your usage should be:

1. call `getJSON`, while passing it a callback that will be invoked when the response is received from the server
2. populate your `books` observable array

Something along these lines:

```
$.getJSON(baseUri, function(data) {
    self.books(data.$values);
});
```

The way you do it now is incorrect for 2 reasons:

1. you don't pass a callback into `getJSON`
2. even if did work and `getJSON` would, somehow, be able to just dump data onto your `books` - it would override the observable array without KO or bound DOM knowing about it.

EDIT: to clarify the last point - `books` is, conincidentally, a function, but the data that it will get populated with is not the one that should be populated onto the `books`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! To say honestly my understanding of knockout js based on some examples that I didi modified to my needs, but not on deep understanding as your.

Comment: There are two resources I consider absolute must for any KO aficionado - the KO docs, naturally, and Ryan's http://www.knockmeout.net/ blog.